# How to draw an "unordered" line chart with Java with reasonable effort?

Tags: java, graph, jfreechart

I want to draw a line through a number of points with Java. I researched JFreeChart and drew around for a half a day but linechart and all other relevant classes I could find drew an "ordered" graph dependent on time. However, I need something like this in which the line can go "back left again".

I want to draw something like this

[image]

Most likely I just need to be told how this kind of chart is called in English and I will be able to research how to draw it.

Comment: In maths, this is a parametric curve: `x = x(t), y = y(t)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JFreeChart Scatter Plot Lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290812/jfreechart-scatter-plot-lines)